# So I have an HTML link that needs one attribute which exists in MVC input

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

```
<a href="https://yourwater.oregon.gov/dcoliform.php?pwsno=$('#PWS').val()" target="_blank" id="DataOnline">Data Online</a>
```

The MVC input is:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PWS)
```

I've referenced this input in all sorts of javascript like document.onload().
But not sure how to send it in a URL name/value pair
The URL is correct. It just won't send the 5 digit number. 
This is what it should like like in the webpage when it gets it:

```
href="https://yourwater.oregon.gov/dcoliform.php?pwsno=99999
```

(99999 is a water system number used for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an html like this -

```
<a href="https://yourwater.oregon.gov/dcoliform.php?pwsno=" target="_blank" id="DataOnline">Data Online</a>
<input type="text" id="PWS" value="99999" />
```

You can easily write a script to do this. This can be in a click handler or on page load or onchange, depends on your requirement.

```
var hreftxt = $("#DataOnline").attr("href");
$("#DataOnline").attr("href", hreftxt + $('#PWS').val());
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgwqu3tx/2/):

Comment: Yes. Works great. PWS number is dynamic and your syntax picks it right up on change event. Thank you very much.